# Is there a need for a third transistor in a NAND gate?

Tags: transistors, nand

I was attempting to create my "own" NAND-gate S/R latch using NPN transistors (I know there are ICs available for that)

From my own knowledge of how transistors work, I came up with this circuit for a NAND gate:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fggg2N.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I also encountered a different approach when looking for implementations on the Internet:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftOvi0.png)</sup>

It seems to me that the 3 transistor variant could have its uses. I did recognize it as an open collector, so I assume it should be used when the output signal should be different from the voltage at SW1's collector.
In the example, both SW1 and SW3 use 5V at the collector, so it is not really necessary I think.

Is there another reason why I would need a third transistor?

Comment: Do you have the original source where the second design came from? I see no reason to choose the second design in the way shown.

Comment: Q,SW2 will conduct across the base-emitter junction when Q,SW1 is turned off. The result won't be a NAND gate.

Comment: @JarrodChristman Yes, the first schematic is valid. It is the second schematic that has a flaw using NPN transistors, which the OP intends to use "using NPN transistors"

Comment: @sstobbe, ah, I didn't see that actually, you're correct.

Comment: You could fix that second circuit by adjusting resistor values.  Maybe.

Comment: This has all been **super thoroughly thought out** back in the 1960's.  Search on the key words "history", "RTL" and "DTL" -- with luck, you'll find the actual circuits that people used to make computers out of when it was done with discrete components on a board.  ("RTL" = "resistor-transistor logic" and "DTL" = "diode transistor logic").  Note that in IC form, RTL and DTL were exceedingly short-lived on the market, because TTL was better in nearly every way.  Search on "history" and "TTL" for info.